# Meteor private messaging between users

Tags: meteor

Right now I have a working messaging system developed in Meteor where users can send private messages to each other.

The server looks like this:

```
// .. lot of code
Meteor.publish("privateMessages", function () {
    return PMs.find({ to: this.userId });
});
PMs.allow({
    insert: function(user, obj) {
        obj.from = user;
        obj.to = Meteor.users.findOne({ username: obj.to })._id;
        obj.read = false;
        obj.date = new Date();
        return true;
    }
});
// .. other code
```

When the user subscribes to privateMessages, he gets a mongo object that looks like this:

```
{ "to" : "LStjrAzn8rzWp9kbr", "subject" : "test", "message" : "This is a test", "read" : false, "date" : ISODate("2014-07-05T13:37:20.559Z"), "from" : "sXEre4w2y55SH8Rtv", "_id" : "XBmu6DWk4q9srdCC2" }
```

How can I change the object to return the username instead of the user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do so in a way similar to how you changed `username` to `_id`. You can create a utility function:

```
var usernameById = function(_id) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(_id);
  return user && user.username;
};
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to poll minimongo for each message, just include `username` instead of `_id` inside your message object. Since `username` is unique, they will be enough.

If in your app you allow users to change `username`, it might be a good idea to *also* keep the `_id` for the record.

In one of larger apps I've been working with we kept user's `_id` in the model (to create links to profile etc.), as well as cached his `profile.name` (for display purposes).

Comment: Return value wants to be `user.username` here, not `&& username`.

Comment: I could do it, but it would require to loop through all the mongodb documents and it will impact performance (when there are many messages, for example)

Comment: @Stennie actually I think if `user` is truthy, it will return the value of `user.username`, not a boolean value as I assume you expect.

Comment: I had an error in the code before. Thanks, @Stennie, for noticing.

Comment: If you want to avoid looking through user collection each time just store username in the message instead of (or along with) _id.

Comment: @HubertOG great idea... why didn't I think about it? :) Please add it to your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest adding the collection helpers package from atmosphere. Then create a helper for PMs called toUser that returns the appropriate user. 
Then you can get the name using message.user.name.