# Meteor: send private messages between users

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Can someone please point me to relevant documentation that will help me achieve users securely sending and retrieving private messages to one another.

I looked into the following link on stack [Meteor private messaging between users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587453/meteor-private-messaging-between-users) and getting a good idea of whats going on. But any additional docs or stack examples would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure but this may help a bit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njS6D5CeR9I

Comment: This guy has created very informative tutorials. The chat app includes the essentials of what I intend to create. Thanks iAmME!

Comment: that guy is me, IAMME, do subscribe for more

Comment: brilliant I will subscribe and thumbs up on youtube. Please lookout for my next question, it involved your tutorial #4. Meteor JS - custom Login for meteor.

Everything works fine until signing into an account approx 10min in the vid.